# basic authentication for websockets

Tags: google-chrome, node.js

When I create a new websocket using chrome

```
new WebSocket('ws://gert:passwd@127.0.0.1:8001/dbname')
```

The nodejs server receives

```
GET /dbname HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: '  5 5) 4 1e   a9 9 0 19
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 3000909100 Q
```

How can I retrieve gert and passwd?

Comment: I hope those aren't the real username and password.

Comment: @user142019 OP is using the localhost IP, how does it matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

is seems like chrome does not pass basic auth data in ws headers indeed.
Why not have login/pwd as part of url query string? (and use secure wss)

Comment: I find it much cleaner the basic auth way? (ssl is my next step, first need to figure out this) Do you think it is a chrome bug?

Comment: It does send cookies in headers. Not sure if there is anything about ws basic auth in the protocol. In any case you can't rely on auth headers right now

Answer (score 8):

[The `Authorization` header was not mentioned in the WebSocket spec until Hybi-13](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-13#page-21).  Chrome implements hybi-00 and hybi-10 (depending on the version of Chrome) so it wasn't a requirement of the implementation.

Now that it's mentioned in the protocol, maybe Google will implement it, but I wouldn't guarantee putting "user:pass@..." in the URI would necessarily be the way to do it, it might require a change to the browser's WebSocket API.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome was not passing the authorization header as part of upgrade request. That resulted in authentication failure.

The issue seems to be fixed in the latest chromium [Here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123862)

Comment: How to find the version of Chromium on that issue page ?

Answer (score 4):

### SSL

I found this [link on Quora](http://www.quora.com/When-working-with-websockets-is-it-advisable-to-authenticate-the-user-on-every-message-or-only-when-the-socket-is-opened).

I agree you could use SSL and just sent those credentials as first message.

### Socket.io

You could also use socket.io which also has websockets transport to do [authorizing](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing)

Comment: @Gert you should probably use socket.io, because websocket are not yet supported in most browsers. If you are going to use it internally you can probably use it, but else a lot of users can't use your site. Also socket.io has a very nice API that looks a lot like websockets, but is websockets+ if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does send cookies with websocket connections. If you have a session cookie you can use the session cookie to identify the user initiating the websocket connection.