# SignalR - how does a web client connect to a self-hosted hub with basic auth and SSL

Tags: ssl, https, forms-authentication, signalr, basic-authentication

We have a self-hosted (in a console app) SignalR hub that uses both Basic Authentication and SSL.

The hub class is:

```
[HubName("TestingHub")]
[Authorize(Mode=AuthorizeMode.Both)]
public class TestingHub : Hub
{
    public void TestMethod(int arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arg: {0}", arg); 
    }

    public string TestWebClientCall(string message)
    {
        Clients.Caller.clientFunction(string.Format("From the server : {0}", message));
        return "Call Worked";
    }
}
```

The self-hosting is done as follows:

```
var url = "https://localhost:3232/";
var server = new Server(url);
server.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
var authoriser = new Authoriser();
server.HubPipeline.AddModule(new AuthorizeModule(authoriser, authoriser));
server.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
server.MapHubs();            
server.Start();
```

The Authoriser class is:

```
public class Authoriser : IAuthorizeHubConnection, IAuthorizeHubMethodInvocation
{
    bool isAuthorised(HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity)
    {
        var authorised = Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(identity.Name, identity.Password);
        return authorised;
    }

    public bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        var identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)request.User.Identity;
        return isAuthorised(identity);
    }

    public bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext)
    {
        var identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.User.Identity;
        return isAuthorised(identity);
    }
}
```

Then the MVC Razor page javascript is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hubUrl = "https://localhost:3232/";
    $.connection.hub.url = hubUrl;
    var hub = $.connection.TestingHub;
    if (hub == undefined) {
        alert("hub not found at " + hubUrl);
    }
    else {

        $.extend(hub, {
            clientFunction: function (textMessage) {
                alert("clientFunction called : " + textMessage);
            }
        });

        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function() {
                hub.server.testWebClientCall('Hello from the client')
                .done(function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("could not connect!");
            });
    }

});
```

Here's what happens:

1. The page loads and pops up the Basic Auth login box - the username/password are put in
2. The Basic Auth login box pops up again - I'm guessing for the script include for the SignalR/hubs
3. The 'hub' object is valid - i.e. the 'TestingHub' can be seen
4. The $.connection.hub.start() call always goes to the .fail and the hub.server.testWebClientCall is never even attempted.

The SSL certificate is all setup fine for the self-hosting as we can access from a .NET console app client.

So the question is really, how should this be done against this self-hosted hub with both Basic Auth and SSL involved?  How do I pass the username/password combination through to the SignalR hub/call to get past the authentication?

For reference, we are testing this kind of approach because we currently have an MVC3 site that is secured via Forms Authentication over HTTPS/SSL and as per another one of my questions, accessing a non-secure self-hosted SignalR hub (i.e. non HTTPS/SSL) from an MVC site under HTTP/SSL doesn't seem to work.

In the SignalR samples I've found details on authorization with regards to 'hosting' (i.e. the AuthHub class) but I can't find anything about how to connect from a web client - there seems to be a lack of 'real world' samples - i.e. with full authentication and SSL encryption.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot host SignalR on ASP.NET?

Does removing the AuthorizeModule from the HubPipeline prevent $.connection.hub.start() from failing? That seems unrelated to me.

What responses are you receiving from the negotiate and/or connect requests?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with Self host or SSL. I think you're asking how do you pass a user name and password to a service that expects a basic auth from javascript (the "web client"). There's no way to change headers with SignalR JS API so you're our of luck there.

Doing something like this might help:

http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html

You can try using $.ajaxSetup to affect all outgoing ajax requests but I'm not sure this will work for websockets.

Seems websockets doesn't support the Auhtorization header:

[basic authentication for websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714966/basic-authentication-for-websockets)

So you'll have to resort to using the query string.

Comment: hi David, we've now got the connection stuff working and the server/client callbacks working in a test project.  This all works once the user has put in username/password details in when that page tries to load the signalr/hubs javascript.  We're now trying to get it to load that dynamically using the approaches you suggested to get the authentication headers right - but it doesn't seem to be working - it's always popping up the login box due to the basic authentication being on the self-hosted hub.  Just wondering if you'd ever tried this?

Comment: I don't understand. What is popping up the login box? Which thing?

Comment: The browser pops up the login box because of the basic authentication on the self-hosted hub - when the page tries to load the signalr/hubs javascript.

Comment: I don't see how you can work around that. It's browser specific behavior and it has nothing do with being self hosted.

Comment: Anyways, I've answered the question and would rather not discuss another issue in comments. Ping me in jabbr if you have another more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code before making a SignalR connection:

```js
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "your auth token"
      }
    });
```

The good news is: SignalR works with auth!

The bad news is: SignalR falls back to long poll from websocket.

I prefer to this because I can't accept any ugly parameter in url or method call at all!